# How can i restrict access to a Azure VM Windows Server machine when browsing?

Tags: azure, window

Currently users browse to service running on a windows machine on a specific port via the following in their browser, the windows machine is s VM in Azure

```
http://<url>:<port_number>
```

How can i restrict certain users from access the machine depending on machine name ?

Not sure where or what to try , hence needing some ideas

Comment: Configure the Windows Firewall to block incoming traffic on specific ports used by web browsers.

Comment: thankyou i will try that , can i restrict via machine name ? Because if they use a dhcp server then ip address may change on a daily basis ?

Comment: @Christy Hi it would be great if you provide more details like what you have tried and where you are getting blockers.

Comment: I have tried to restrict access to a VM via the Inbound rules in Azure .  Now this only allows you to restrict ip addresses. Users run on a dhcp server so ip may change . So is there a way in Azure to restrict the user , not by machine ip but by AD User name ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @dtthom09 you can Configure the Windows Firewall to block incoming traffic. As you already mentioned particular Ip address can be restricted by using inbound and outbound Ip addresses.

Azure portal>> Created Virtual machine>> Networking>> Add inbound security rule. Here by mentioning Source and Destination Ip address and port range we can restrict.
[image]

```
Azure to restrict the user , not by machine ip but by AD User name ?
```

- **Yes. you can do it by configuring role assignment to your virtual machine** by following this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows#configure-role-assignments-for-the-vm).As per this document **you need to set up an Azure RBAC policy to control who can access the VM** by adding *Virtual Machine Administrator* Login role or *Virtual Machine User Login* role in role assignments.
- In my case role assignment is disabled can't proceed further but you can follow below steps.
  **Created Azure virtual machine >> Access control >>Add >> Add role assignment**. Then take the roles as mentioned in Ms document.

[image]

- By following that Ms document you can do it in azure portal and in Azure CLI also

```
    $username=$(az account show --query user.name --output tsv)
    $rg=$(az group show --resource-group myResourceGroup --query id -o tsv)
    
    az role assignment create \
        --role "Virtual Machine Administrator Login" \
        --assignee $username \
        --scope $rg
```

- you can also create custom role in AAD and then you can add this created custom role in VM add role assignment . For this follow below steps.

1. Choose Azure Active Directory>> Roles and administrators >> New custom role. In this mention the custom role a name and a description .
2. Then the resource type should be "Virtual Machines," and the action should be "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/*."
3. Select "Add a condition" and then select "User" as the type.
4. Enter the AD user or group that you want to allow access to the VM.
5. Select "Review + create" and then "Create"
6. Then Go to Created VM >> Access control>>Add role assignment>> then Select the custom role that you created and then select the AD user or group that you want to allow access to the VM and  Select Save.

**Note**: you need to check whether your role assignment is enabled or disabled as shown in below image. if it is enable you can add roles based on your requirement or else you need to reach out who can add these.

Also Refer this Ms [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/azure/virtual-network-manager/how-to-block-network-traffic-portal) it may helps.

Comment: Will this work even if a user uses a browser to browse to a service that runs on a particular port on the windows machine using http://<url>:<port_number>, as it is not rdp ?

Comment: @Christy  No matter what kind of access users are attempting to gain to the VM, Azure RBAC policies can be used to restrict access to it. Regardless of the mechanism they employ, it only regulates which users are permitted to access the VM.

So, every user attempting to access the service running on the VM via a browser on any port will be subject to the same access limitations if you have configured an Azure RBAC policy to restrict access to the Windows VM based on AD user name.